# Multiple zeta values at negative integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions

For a tuple of integers $\underline{s}:=(s_1,\dots, s_d)$, the multiple zeta value (MZV) at $\underline{s}$ is defined as:
$$ \zeta(s_1,\dots, s_d):= \sum_{n_1>\dots>n_d>0}\frac 1 {n_1^{s_1}\dots n_d^{s_d}}.$$

In all the references I have seen, people restrict to tuples $\underline{s}$ such that $s_1 > 1$ and $s_i \geq 1$ for all $i\geq 2$, mentionning convergence of the series.

However, it seems to me that this series converges as soon as $s_1>1$, $s_1+s_2>2$, \dots, $s_1 + \dots s_d>d$ which allows more MZV at integers.
For example, $\zeta(5,-1)$ converges.

My question is twofold:

1) Have these MZV at "negative integers" been studied and are they "number theoretically interesting"?

2)I also understand that there should be a reason to exclude these values and that they don't fit in the general philosophy about MZV.
For example, we would have a non trivial relation such as $\zeta(s,0)=\zeta(s-1) -\zeta(s)$ between MZV of different weights.
(The weight of $\underline{s}$ is by definition $s_1+\dots s_d$. As far as I understood, the general belief is that all relations between MZV are generated by relations between MZV of the same weight but I don't think that the one above can.)

Is there an a priori good reason to restrict to positive integers?

Comment: I was under the impression that negative input values are also sometimes considered by using some kind of regularization.  Unfortunately, I don't have a reference.

Comment: I think Goncharov's article on periods and mixed motives doesn't restrict to positive integers.

Comment: @S. Carnahan: as far as I understand, regularization has to do with giving a meaning to diverging series sur as $\zeta(1,2)$. But the series I refer to do converge.


Answer (score 2):

In response to 1: Yes, these have been studied, for example, in *Multiple zeta values at non-positive integers*
[(2001)](http://math.tsukuba.ac.jp/~akiyama/papers/Mzvnrev.pdf) and [(2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X14002350), see also *The first derivative multiple zeta values at non-positive integers* [(2010)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11139-009-9201-1) and *Analytic continuation of multiple zeta-functions and the asymptotic behavior at non-positive integers* [(2013)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.facm/1387572236).